# Exe creation using pyinstaller for django rest app

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, pyinstaller, exe

I am trying to create an exe file using Pyinstaller for Django project having only REST api framework used.

I am trying to create exe file by giving command pyinstaller --onefile -w manage.py, file is executing but not giving any error or output and server also not starting.
Could someone please help on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it. I removed --onefile flag and created exe file using
pyinstaller manage.py. By default, it created directory and exe file created in that worked.